# Which thread to use for saving images to SD card

Tags: android, multithreading

Wondering what is the most appropriate thread to use for a process like saving image from camera to SD card and updating UI with success/failed messages (toasts)..
A handler or asynchronous thread?
Also can a asynchronous thread take a Bitmap as a parameter ?

Thanks
Ciaran

Comment: an handler is not a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
                Boolean saved = writeToDisk(bitmaps[0]); //Your write code
                return saved;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean saved) {
                if (saved) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //HANDLE SUCCESS
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //HANDLE ERROR
                }
            }
        };

        task.execute(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks, used the asynch thread worked fine. So when would you use a thread handler??

Answer (score 1):

The asynctask class is great for what you want to achieve you can pass bitmap as a parameter to asynctask.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not allow to use networking on the UI thread (that is handling events like button clicks). Also, it does not allow any slow operations on that thread as they would stall the whole GUI.

I am not sure if this applies to SD-card writing. This may depend from the amount of data you need to write there. If it is in order of megabytes or close to that, using a separate thread for writing to SD-card makes sense beyond any doubt as the writing process may last long enough. Maybe even for less.